# sorting non-alphanumeric characters in ASCII order in R

Tags: r, sorting, ascii

any idea how to sort a character vector containing non-alphanumeric characters by the ASCII order (like C)? an example to illustrate:

```
> v<-c("#1-adfgh3$","-d","!cd3&")
> sort(v)
[1] "-d"         "!cd3&"      "#1-adfgh3$"
```

yet "!" should be coming before "-" in the ASCII order.

thanks very much.

cheers,
john

Comment: If you read `?sort` carefully, you'll see a note at the bottom with a link to some discussion of collation issues in R that probably sheds some light on the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an idea:

```
asciiSort <- function(vec) {
    x <- sapply(vec, 
                function(X) {
                    paste0(strtoi(charToRaw(X), base=16), collapse="")
                })
    vec[order(x)]
}

asciiSort(v)
# [1] "!cd3&"      "#1-adfgh3$" "-d"
```

Comment: Running `Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")` also seemed to work for me, but I have absolutely no clue how reliable that might be.

Comment: @joran -- That seems far preferable to me, but I also have no idea how general/portable a solution it is. (I do think that once you start passing my function non-ASCII characters, all bets are off.)